# Batch para crear copias de seguridad incrementales sin sobrescribir archivos en destino

Tags: windows, script, batch

Tengo dos carpetas en Windows, una llamada **DATOS** y otra llamada **COPIAS**, serían los directorios origen y destino, respectivamente. Mediante la ejecución de un batch puedo crear copias del contenido en origen al directorio destino, usando *ROBOCOPY*, por ejemplo.

La primera copia que hago es completa, es decir:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\DATOS D:\COPIAS
```

Al día siguiente, vuelvo a ejecutar el batch, pero esta vez sólo me interesa que se copien los archivos nuevos o modificados desde la última copia, haría tal que así:

```
ROBOCOPY C:\DATOS D:\COPIAS \XO
```

La instrucción `\XO` *(e**X**clude **O**lders)*, excluye ficheros más antiguos. Esto funciona correctamente, y está bien.

Ahora viene el problema:

Deseo que la ejecución del batch **no me sobrescriba** los archivos que ya se encuentran en el destino, sino que me los copie como un documento nuevo (`mi libro (1).docx`, por ej). Esto para que, en caso de cometer un error en el archivo origen, yo pueda escoger entre las versiones anteriores de mi directorio destino a modo de recuperación. Algo así como Dropbox, que puedes ver un histórico de las versiones de un mismo archivo.

Buscando en la [información oficial del comando ROBOCOPY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) no encuentro alguna instrucción que me indique cómo proceder.

Igualmente intenté revisando [estas consultas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4228925/9609518) en el sitio en inglés, pero no funcionan en entorno real:

```
robocopy c:\Sourcepath c:\Destpath /E /XC /XN /XO
```

También con el comando XCOPY:

```
echo n | copy /-y <SOURCE> <DESTINATION>
```

Este último simplemente no sobrescribe, pero tampoco copia, es decir, no hace nada.

Existe otra alternativa? Le ha sucedido un problema similar a alguien en la comunidad?

Gracias por su tiempo y atención.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robocopy no soporta lo que necesitas, así que lo tendrás que hacer tu programáticamente. Un lenguaje de programación como python, ruby, php o perl te dará más flexibilidad.

Sin embargo si quieres una solución puramente batch podrías hacer algo **similar** a esto. Te presento un ejemplo básico en el que los archivos cambiados se copian agregando " - copia x" (con 'x' adicionales)

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('xcopy /L /D /Y C:\datos\* D:\copias\ ^| findstr /I /C:"C:\\datos\\"') do (
    set fichero=%%~na
    set extension=%%~xa
    set copia=!fichero! - copia x
    if exist "D:\copias\!copia!!extension!" (
        for /F "delims=" %%x in ('dir /B /ON "D:\copias\!copia!*!extension!"') do (
            set copia=%%~nx
        )
    
        set copia=!copia!x
    )
    echo Copiando... "C:\datos\!fichero!!extension!" a "D:\copias\!copia!!extension!"
    copy "C:\datos\!fichero!!extension!" "D:\copias\!copia!!extension!"
)
```

La idea es llamar a `xcopy` con el parámetro `/D` (que hace que solo se intenten "copiar" los ficheros que han cambiado) y con `/L` (que **no** copia los ficheros, únicamente imprime lo que va a copiar)

De esta manera obtienes un listado de lo que ha cambiado.

Este listado lo puedes 'capturar' y recorrer con el buble `FOR`. Te recopiendo esta [lectura](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) para ver todas las opciones que permite la instrucción FOR y cómo funciona.

Para cada fichero que sabemos que ha cambiado, miraremos si existe alguna versión " - copia x" en el destino y en tal caso nos quedaremos con la que tenga más 'x's.

Esto lo hacemos capturando la salida del comando `DIR`, ordenando por nombre de fichero.

Para el tema de añadir "x"s adicionales te recomiendo esta otra [lectura](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) donde se explican las extensiones de los parámetros. Las extensiones se utilizan para entre otras cosas 'separar' de una ruta de un fichero su extensión, el fichero sin la ruta, etc.

Finalmente hacemos la copia del fichero al destino con el "nombre copia"